# Notepad++ How to copy the last x characters of every line to the end of the same line?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, text-editing, replacement

Example-

This:

> *Example/Images/**1234567***

Needs to become this:

> *Example/Images/1234567**1234567***

1234567 is a random string of 7 alphanumeric characters on each line.

Comment: look  up capture groups, and form a pattern dividing the line up into 2 capture groups; everything up to and including the last slash, and everything after. then your replace pattern will be like `$1$2$2` so that your second captured group (the filename) is duplicated. if you have file extensions, split into 3 groups, and replace with `$1$2$2$3`. hope tht helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\w{7}$`
- Replace with: `$0$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\w{7}       # 7 alphanumeric characters
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0$0        # twice the whole match
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!